# Backbone pass different max values to template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This theoretically seems kind of easy but I am not 100% on the appropriate code to write.

Inside a view if I am defining a max variable that returns an attribute `points` in a collection, I can pass that variable as an object into my template like `maxPoints.toJSON()` and get that object's attributes.

```
var maxPoints = this.collection.max(function(player){
    return player.get('team') == home || player.get('team') == away ? player.get('points') : 0;
});

//Pass to template
this.$el.find('.top-preformer').append(this.template(maxPoints.toJSON()));

//Inside the template using underscore.js I can get the `name` of the object returned
<%= name %>

//Easy, but now I am passing two objects, how do I access `name` for top points
//or `name` for top assists?
```

This is fine, but what if I want to retrieve multiple max values and interact with them inside the template?

```
var maxAssists = this.collection.max(function(player){
    return player.get('team') == home || player.get('team') == away ? player.get('assists') : 0;
});
```

Now I have an object `maxAssists` that I could pass into my template, but I am not sure how this would work. How could I interact with each specific object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if this answer isn't appropriate now that you've deleted your previous question and asked another one. This is the answer I was about to send when you deleted your question:

---

I hope I've correctly understood your scenario. Let me sum it up just in case:

*There's a `Model`, let's call it `Player`, which represents a player with a `name`, a `team`, `points` and `assists` (at least). There's a `Collection` of `Players` which is held by the `View` you're referring to. This `View` shows stuff about players and also highglights the player with most points and the one with most assists.*

I'm assuming too much about your needs, but let's say you want to show a list of players with their info and then the info of those highlighted. Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e38U/3/) I prepared to show my approach.

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't set data in the DOM unless it's extrictly necessary, that's why you're using JavaScript after all. Since you have a `View` which holds a `Collection`, that `View` should be the one to hold references to both most points player and most assists player. Using your `max` functions, you may do it this way:

```
getMaxPointsPlayer: function () {
    return this.getMax("points");
},

getMaxAssistsPlayer: function () {
    return this.getMax("assists");
},

getMax : function (attribute) {
    return this.collection.max(function (player) {
        return player.get("team") === this.homeTeam || player.get("team") === this.awayTeam ? player.get(attribute) : 0;
    }, this);
},
```

Note two things:

- You should always use `===` instead of `==` where possible. Search this site for more info on it.
- Since I don't know where those `home` and `away` variables are in your code and what are them, I placed them as *member variables* in the view (and they're just strings).

So, when you want to reference the player with most points/assists, you'd call one of those functions which are part of the `View`. Then you may store it in a variable (so you can get it without further filtering) or use it straight away from the call to the function.

If you study the code in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e38U/3/), you'll see more stuff than you asked for. It's there to show you a nice way to keep your application clean and tidy (obviously, it's just a JSFiddle). Try to keep `Views` on their own business (may it be present and deal with a `Model`, have a list of *sub-views* and manage them because they're part of a `Collection` or just be a manager of other *sub-views*). That way, those views have the logic they need without dealing with data in the DOM.

Comment: Oh wow sorry, I always fret if I deleted a question I may be wasting someones time, but I didn't feel I was clear enough or I made it over confusing, so I decided to try and simpilify it with a new question. Thanks for the effort, got a fresh cup of coffee about to read into your answer I bet I learn something, thanks!

Comment: Good read, thanks for all that. I am setting the `id` of the max object as a data-attribute so that I can add a transition to the element when the `id` changes the data attribute changes and I can add a transition when that happens, I could add a transition without that but since it renders its hard to determine if the object is a new one. I bet I can think of a better way, but its relatively hard to determine if the object changes values, sure there is a backbone.js way to determine if new max value isn't equal to old then do something.

Comment: I think I haven't understood you then. You are storing the `id` so you can create a transition when the `id` changes? Who changes the `id`, which transition you are performing and to which element?

Comment: The id attribute is really a separate concern don't worry about that lol in your answer you talk about why not to use the DOM to store data. I was explaining I did it so I could write a function to check if that data-attribute does not equal the prior attribute, if it returns true that it does not equal then I run a transition. This is because when interacting with the app the leading scorer may remain the leading scorer after rendering, you would not want a transition then, but if there is a new leader that passes up the old leader you want a transition.

Comment: Your answer is fine so far, don't worry I am fiddling away trying to suit a few things to my needs but based on the fiddle it looks good. Plugged in the methods to my code, the methods work great and return the appropriate leader in my render method. I would just like to pass the object as JSON to the template to access the `name` of the points leader and the `name` of the assists leader, that's it :)

Comment: Alright :) Anyway, I don't know if you may take advantage of this, but remember `Views` can listen to `Model` and `Collection` changes using `listenTo()`. That way, in your view you can hold a reference to your current top scorer (the model) and when any of the player's score changes you re-run that `max` function. Finally, check if that new top scorer is the one you had referenced. If not, then create that transition. This way you avoid using the DOM ^^

Comment: Glad I could help anyway!

Comment: 1+ I like this code, but instead of instantiating the `playerView` I just want to return information from the object into a template on it's own. I totally see why you did it that way, but I am working in a separate view and would like to structure it based on the attributes.

Comment: You did a good job, I am just primarily confused on passing and accessing the objects inside the underscore.js template. something like `<%= name.assists %>` `<%= name.points %>`

Comment: Well I used this syntax `this.getMaxAssistsPlayer().get('name')` it works fine, any tips on that regard, maybe simplifying it or passing both objects as JSON etc? Going to mark your answer soon!! :)

Comment: Remember you can pass *anything* to the template. You could do something like `this.$el.html(this.template({ maxPoints : this.getMaxPointsPlayer(), maxAssists : this.getMaxAssistsPlayer() }))`. Then, in your template you can do `<%= maxPoints.get("name") %>` and `<%= maxAssists.get("name")`, or any attribute / variable you want.

Comment: Ah perfect, yeah I have been through this hundreds of times, I cant believe I missed that the key is `maxPoints: this.getMaxPointsPlayer()` `maxPoints` then becomes accessable, I forgot that, even though I have done it multiple times and that truly is what I was missing. I picked up those method(s) you created and am going to stick to that thanks!!!